# SwiftUI Nested ObservableObject and FetchRequest

Tags: swiftui, core-data, combine

I'm expecting that the `Edit child name` button updates the `View` but don't

```swift
import SwiftUI
import CoreData

struct ContentView: View {
    @FetchRequest(
        sortDescriptors: [NSSortDescriptor(keyPath: \Parent.name, ascending: true)],
        animation: .default)
    private var parents: FetchedResults<Parent>
    
    init(){
        let parent = Parent(context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
        parent.child = Child(context: PersistenceController.shared.container.viewContext)
        parent.anyCancellable = parent.child!.objectWillChange.sink { (_) in
            parent.objectWillChange.send()
        }
    }
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Edit parent name"){
                parents.first!.name = "Edited parent name"
            }
            Button("Edit child name"){
                parents.first!.child!.name = "Edited child name" //<<--!!! Not updates the View
            }
            ForEach(parents) { parent in
                Text(parent.name!)
                Text(parent.child!.name!)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Every `Parent` & `Child` has to be wrapped in `@ObservedObject` to see changes. Create subviews so you can achieve this.

Answer (score 1):

It's best to do this with core data rather than combine. Eg using `observeValueForKeyPath` as explained in the To-Many Relationship section here

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/Articles/KVODependentKeys.html

However usually it's best to avoid this and design your entity around how you want your data to display on each screen so it's just a simple fetch request.